# Can't link to iconv on OS X

Tags: macos, cmake, macports, iconv, ninja

I'm trying to build a library with CMake that depends on iconv. I've installed it with Macports but whenever I try to build the library I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in my_charset.c.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in my_charset.c.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _mariadb_convert_string in my_charset.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have a `FindIconv.cmake` file that seems to be looking in the right place. What could go wrong?

Comment: Try `ninja -v` to get the actual link command, and try to reproduce it manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are likely mismatching which library/headers you are using.  It looks like you compiled your source code using headers from /usr/include and are trying to link against /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib

```
~ $ nm -m /usr/lib/libiconv.dylib | grep iconv_close
0000000000002ea4 (__TEXT,__text) external _iconv_close

~ $ nm -m /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib | grep iconv_close
0000000000003ec0 (__TEXT,__text) external _libiconv_close
```

Make sure you compile with -I/opt/local/include

Comment: FindIconv.cmake seems to point in the right direction though.